# Function Inside of Style Components Passing Variable

Tags: reactjs, function, object, styled-components

I have a list of categories.
Each category has its own color.
I want to pass the category name as a ref to Style Components and have the Styled Component pass the category as string to a function which maps the string to the appropriate color value.

The idea is to have the category color vals in a separate file and reference them.

I currently have this.

```
<Container
onClick={playChannel}
category={category}>

const Container = styled.div`
  background: ${colorFromTheme(({ category }) => category)};
`;

const colorFromTheme = val => ({ theme }) => {
  let color = val;
  console.log(val);

  if (Object.keys(theme).includes(val)) {
    color = theme[color];
  }

  return val;
};
```

This is all currently passing vals along.
Theme is a js file of consts that are exported.
I am getting an error where val is coming back as a function.
However, if I just return val without conditional, I see in Dev Console that the name of the category I pass it comes back.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do

`<Container
onClick={playChannel}
background={colorFromTheme(category)}>`

and

`const Container = styled.div
  background: ${({background}) => background};`